# redirect safari traffic through ssh

Tags: mac, safari, ssh

Hi I'm following this tutorial to redirect safari traffic through ssh,

https://helpdesk.eoas.ubc.ca/kb/articles/how-to-ssh-tunnel-a-connection-using-macos

which is first
ssh -D 8080 -N user@address
this command will return nothing, and stay there, seems like connected,

then I set the safari port as in the tutorial,
[image]

however this does work, safari still not able to visit google,

Comment: Can you run `ssh -v ...` and check whether anything "interesting" shows up? Does it work if you use Chrome instead (`cd /App*/G*Chrome.app/C*/MacOS; ./Google\ Chrome --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:8080" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost"`)?